# Cannot add extra-deps to Stack project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to set up a Haskell project with Stack. I have created a project: `stack new project1` and added the suggested dependency (acme-missile) just to see how it works.

```
extra-deps:
- acme-missiles-0.3
```

But when I try to invoke `launchMissile` in the Main it won't work. I get

```
Error:(3, 1)     Could not find module ‘Acme.Missiles’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Acme.Missiles
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is the problem? What am I missing?

**EDIT**

When I run `stack solver` I get this:

```
Using configuration file: stack.yaml
Using cabal packages:
- ./


The following changes will be made to stack.yaml:
* Dependencies to be deleted
    extra-deps:
    - acme-missiles-0.3

To automatically update stack.yaml, rerun with '--update-config'
```

Isn't that strange? Like it thinks my dependency is not needed?

Comment: Does the code compile when you run `stack build`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann nope. I get the error message I included when I run stack build

Comment: No errors before that one?

Comment: @MarkSeemann no

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to add the dependency to `project1.cabal` as well:

```
build-depends:
    base >=4.7 && <5
  , project1
  , acme-missiles
```

Alternatively, on newer versions of Stack, it looks like you should use `package.yaml` instead:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- acme-missiles
```

I can't say that I have deep knowledge of how this works, but if I understand it correctly, the main file where you're supposed to add dependencies is in the `.cabal` or `package.yaml` file. The `extra-deps` field in `stack.yaml` is where you can indicate if you have dependencies that deviate from the LTS that you currently use.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue. If you use newer Stack you should not modify the `.cabal` file by hand, Stack generates it, but it is necessary to add it to the dependencies :)